# using NOT in sqlite query

Tags: android, sqlite

I have never used `NOT` in a query so I don't know if this is right.

```
Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Games.TOTALS_URI, 
                new String[] {Games.TOTALS_FRAME_TOTAL},
                Games.TOTALS_FRAME_NUM+"=10"+" AND "+Games.TOTALS_FRAME_TOTAL+" NOT 0",null,null);
```

I want to get a value only if it is `not 0` or even `> 0` so would that be right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instinct was correct, it should be > 0:

```
" AND "+Games.TOTALS_FRAME_TOTAL+" > 0"
```

Or better yet, to handle the case where `Games.TOTALS_FRAME_TOTAL` might be NULL, wrap it in a COALESCE() function:

```
" AND COALESCE("+Games.TOTALS_FRAME_TOTAL+", 0) > 0"
```

The COALESCE function accepts a list of values and returns the first non-NULL value.